# Input Field accepting any Characters, ignoring Regular Expression

Tags: html, regex, vue.js, input

I have the following regular expression for an `input` field, which was validated as correct:

```
<input type='text' name='email' pattern="[/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/]" />
```

However, my field is accepting any string, ignoring the regex. I am working in Vue.js. What am I missing?

Please note that the Regex was taken from [here](https://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/email-validation.php).

Comment: Remove regex delimiters and brackets, `pattern="\w+(?:[.-]\w+)*@\w+(?:[.-]\w+)*(?:\.\w{2,4})+"`

Comment: Thank you Wiktor! I had actually tried to remove both, but only one at a time, instead of both at the same time... Thank you again for your time.

Comment: In future consider waiting longer before selecting an answer. Quick selections can discourage other answers. Also, keep in mind that others may be working on their answers when they see the green checkmark appear in the corner of their eye (or for some, eyes) shortly after the question is posted. The point is there's no rush, just don't forget to make a selection, provided at least one answer is helpful, of course. My comment has nothing to do with the answer you selected and I had no intention of offering an answer myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
pattern="^\w+([.-]\w+)*@\w+([.-]\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$"
```

The brackets and slashes are not part of the pattern and must be removed.

Mind that special characters lose their special meaning inside brackets, hence use `[.-]` instead of `[\.-]`.

Comment: In those browsers, where the pattern gets compiled with `u` modifier, `[\.-]` will be invalid, so the escape symbol must be dropped before `.`. You may even drop the `^` and `$` anchors, as the patterh must match the entire input.

Comment: Thank you Ryszard!